# Lost in javascript scope

Tags: javascript, event-handling, scope

could someone please help me out with the (simplified) code below. I'm trying to call the `doTheSlide()` function from within the slide event function. I'm still a tad shady on my understanding of scope in JS.

What is a correct way to achieve this? I'm getting this error:

> `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function`

```
(function($) {

    bindEvent = function(slider) {

        slider.bind('slide', function(event, ui) {

            doTheSlide(ui.value);
        });
    }

    doTheSlide = function(value) {
        //Animate the slide
    }


    var methods


})(jQuery);
```

Comment: have you tried putting `var` in from of the variables holding those anon functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to declare 'doTheSlide' somewhere. You seem to be using it as a global function, which is wrong most of the time. Make sure that everything is declared properly (with var or using a named function).

Here is a fixed version of your code (the way I prefer it):

```
(function($) {
    function doTheSlide(value) {
        //Animate the slide
    }

    function bindEvent(slider) {
        slider.bind('slide', function(event, ui) {
            doTheSlide(ui.value);
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Remember to declare functions before they are used. It will work to call a function that is declared later, but it is not good style.

Alternative syntax:

```
(function($) {
    var doTheSlide = function(value) {
        //Animate the slide
    };

    var bindEvent = function(slider) {
        slider.bind('slide', function(event, ui) {
            doTheSlide(ui.value);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting function declarations ahead of function expressions—clearer syntax and takes advantage of "hoisting".